# How to add text to a textfield without overriding the current text?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program where it asks the user for how many numbers to be sorted then randomly generates the amount of numbers the user asks and sorts it. This is my first attempt at using swing on java so im not sure how to go about one of my features. When the user press's sort there are 2 text fields. One is the array of the unsorted numbers and the other field will be where the sorted numbers go. However when I enter the amount of numbers then press sort I should expect the numbers with a comma. Maybe im using the wrong command for the text field but I cant figure it out. I think only the last number is coming up and is the only one that appears.

```
//get data
            String data = txtInput.getText();
            //parse for numerical value
           int  numGenerate = Integer.parseInt(data); 

           int Numbers[]=new int[numGenerate];

           for (int x=0;x<=Numbers.length-1;x++)
           {
               Numbers[x]=(int)(Math.random()*1000)+1;

               txtUnsorted.setText(String.valueOf(Numbers[x])+",");
           }
```

Comment: `setText` overwrites the current text. You need to `getText` and append.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
txtUnsorted.setText(txtUnsorted.getText() + String.valueOf(Numbers[x])+ "," );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't name variable with a capital letter. Only classes should name with a capital letter.
Second thing, you don't have to parse `int` to `String` to print it.
In method setText you put only a number and a comma. You should also put existing value of this field:

```
txtUNsorted.setText(txtUnsorted.getText() + ", " + numbers[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

setText() method replaces the current text. 
So get first txtUnsorted.getText() then assign to variable. Use setText() afterwards.

```
var unsorted = txtUnsorted.getText();
txtUnsorted.setText(unsorted + String.valueOf(Numbers[x])+",");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your first answer! While your proposition seems correct, a few extra sentences explaining what caused the original error and how your proposition solves it would make for a better answer.  Please edit your answer to make it even better!

Answer (score 0):

As [czachodym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8891321/czachodym) said don't begin a variable with an Uppercase letter. Go through this [Java Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) to see the rules and conventions for naming your variables.

And also I don't think you need this statement like this because [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) are `zero-based`,

```
x <= Numbers.length - 1
```

Just change above to the following because following is the correct way to iterate through an array,

```
x < Numbers.length
```

So your entire code should be like this,

```
// get data
String data = txtInput.getText();

// parse for numerical value
int  numGenerate = Integer.parseInt(data); 

int Numbers[] = new int[numGenerate];

for (int x = 0; x < Numbers.length; x++)
{
   Numbers[x] = (int)(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;

   txtUnsorted.setText(Numbers[x] + "," + txtUnsorted.getText()); // or
   txtUnsorted.setText(txtUnsorted.getText() + Numbers[x] + ",");
}
```